# My Notebook can't reboot after reinstall new operating systems without display driver installed?

Tags: windows, drivers, amd-radeon, reboot, display-driver

I  have a small problem when I  reinstalled my notebook with Windows 7 or Windows XP home edition. the problem is I can't reboot my system if I didn't install display driver (ATI-Radeon). I can't reboot my system because of the restart's button on shut down menu disappear, thats mean the system cant be rebooting. And when I install display driver, the reboot button in shutdown menu will be appear, thats mean I cant access reboot menu. I just want to know,

1. Why does it happen?
2. Does the display driver have influence with the reboot process?

Comment: Does only the reboot button on the start menu disappear or the whole start menu? Also what's the model number/manufacture of the notebook?

Comment: yeah, the reboot button on the start menu disappear. the model is Acer AS4738G.

Comment: To clarify the "restart button" is missing but the rest, such as "shut down" are there? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `shutdown` command. Open up the command prompt, `cd %windir%\system32`, and type
`shutdown -r -t 0`. That should tell the OS to reboot. If you're on Windows 7, be sure to start the command prompt as Admin.

As with the reason why this happens, I could only guess that there is some sort of policy defined that denies the user rebooting. If you can access the Group Policy editor, have a look at this page: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-remove-shutdown-from-windows-xp-and-vista/.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking the installer is just a program and can do anything it wants. The question to be asked is why did the author want to disable the restart button? I bet that disabling the restart button can be done by modifying keys in the windows registry.